# changing number of arguments to a function in secondary evaluation

Tags: functions, argument-patterns

So I have a function that produces answers involving uninstantiated(?) function names, e.g.

```
 Out[1]= f[a,b,c,d].
```

I then want to evalute this leftover result by, say, replacing this `f[a,b,c,d]` with a defined function `g[a,b,c,d,e]`.

I think something maybe to do with slots, but my poor attempts have still failed, eg.

```
 Out[1] /. f[##] &@g[##,e]

 Out[1] /. f[___] -> g

 Out[1] /. f[#1, #2, #3, #4] -> g[#1, #2, #3, #4, e]
```

Comment: You're mixing the concepts of pure functions (`#` and `&`) with replacement (`/.`, `->`, `:>`). Use slots with the first one, use patterns (`Pattern` in the documentation, `x_` or `x__` for example in usage) with the second. E.g. `f[a, b, c, d] /. f[x__] :> g[x, e]`.

Comment: Aargh. This comment is an answer! I'll accept it if you want

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From my own comment:

You're mixing the concepts of pure functions (`#` and `&`) with replacement (`/.`, `->`, `:>`). Use slots with the first one, use patterns (`Pattern` in the documentation, `x_` or `x__` for example in usage) with the second.

For this problem:

```
f[a, b, c, d] /. f[x__] :> g[x, e]
```

> g[a, b, c, d, e]

Note the use of `__`, which is two underscores: This is a pattern which grabs 1 or more elements (see also `___` which grabs 0 or more elements), and inserts them as a `Sequence` when used in replacement. Thus, it doesn't get inserted as a `List`.

If you wanted to do this with pure functions, it becomes a bit more complicated:

```
g[Sequence @@ #, e] &[f[a, b, c, d]]
```

> g[a, b, c, d, e]

But note that this isn't dependent on its argument being in the form of `f[...]`, it will replace any functional head. To avoid that requires conditionals of some variety, e.g:

```
If[Head[#] === f, g[Sequence @@ #, e], Undefined] &[f[a, b, c, d]]
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html):

```
g[##, e] & @@ f[a, b, c, d]
```

> g[a, b, c, d, e]

or `ReplaceAll` with replacement rule `f -> (g[##, e] &)`:

```
f[a, b, c, d] /.  f -> (g[##, e] &)
```

> g[a, b, c, d, e]

Answer (score 2):

There is yet another solution, using `Flatten` with `Head` `f`, namely

```
Flatten[g[f[a, b, c, d], e], 1, f]
```

> g[a, b, c, d, e]

This assumes that `g` is not defined for two arguments, otherwise it will evaluate before `Flatten` has a chance so flatten the `f`. If that's not the case one can use `Inactive` on `g`, act with `Flatten` and then `Activate` again.

```
Activate[Flatten[Inactive[g][f[a, b, c, d], e], 1, f]]
```

Comment: you can also use `FlattenAt`: `FlattenAt[g[f[a, b, c, d], e], 1]`  (+1)